# nginx escape_fragment rewrite for static content of angular SPA

Tags: angularjs, nginx, seo

I have an angular SPA and have generated the static html pages so that webcrawlers are able to find and crawl the site. I added the following snippet to my nginx site config.

```
if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_=/?(.+)") {
    set $path $1;
    rewrite ^ /snapshots/$path last;
}
```

While this works fine for all subfolder like pages such as `/abc` that are crawled like `?_escaped_fragment_=abc` it does not work in the case where the root url `/` is crawled  where the `?_escaped_fragment_=` is empty. In that case nginx falls back to `/` and the .js app is served instead of the static content.

Any ideas what a correct rewrite statement would look like? Or where exactly am I missing something? Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem with nginx.

```
# SEO _escaped_fragment_
if ($args ~* "_escaped_fragment_=") {
    rewrite ^ /snapshots/$uri last;
}
```